# remove extra space present between texts

Tags: html, css

we have more space [here](http://stylebaby.com/polka-dots-sony-xperia-z-phone-case.html) b/w `Check COD Availability` & `qty` text

you can search the texts using CTRL + F

i want to reduce those space

```
.block-check-delivery .button {
/*  float: right;   */
position:relative;
left:10px;
  }
.block-check-delivery .block-content > br:first-child {
  display: none;
}

.block-check-delivery .block-content > br:last-child {
  display: none;
}


.block-title {
  float:left;
  position: relative; 
  padding: 10px 0 0; 
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-top: none;
  display: inline-block; 

  }   
  .std ul { 
  list-style: disc outside; 
  /* margin-bottom: 1.5em; */ 
  }
.product-view .product-shop .short-description { margin-bottom: 5px; clear: both; }
.block, .col-left-first  { margin-bottom:10px; }
.block-check-delivery .block-content {padding:0 10px;  }
.block-check-delivery input{width: 107px;}
```

please help me to find solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: @nsdlfefinediecbe are you talking about gap between check cod Availability and qty(vertical)? then simple remove padding-bottom from .block.block-list.block-check-delivery and you will get your answer.

Comment: @Leothelion pls post as an asnwer.

Comment: I did.. please check and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i can see, issue is coming because of **padding-bottom** so just remove padding-bottom from `.block.block-list.block-check-delivery` and you will be free from extra space. Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS

```
 .product-view .product-shop {
  margin-bottom: -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
.block, .col-left-first {
    margin-bottom: -21px;
}
```

Edit: Added missing braces.